# Jmeter JSon Extract multiple values

Tags: json, jmeter

I am trying to extract multiple values from a JSON document through the [JMETER JSON Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLtfW.png) with the following expression: `$..VoidTransactionReferenceNumber;$..CILAmount`

However, I am unable to get desired response, which is the `VoidTransactionReferenceNumber` and `CLIAmount`.

The JSON document is:

```
{
    "VoidTransactionReferenceNumber": "23456", 
    "TransactionDTM": "2017-11-16T10:09:16.343Z", 
    "CardBalance": 2350,
    "CardSequenceNumber": 0,
    "CILAmount": 0,
    "AutoloadAmount": 0,
    "CardBlockState": false, 
    "VoidedAmount": 570, 
    "SalesReferenceNumber": "2051609371", 
    "VoidSalesReferenceNumber": "2051609371",
    "CardNumber": "3085220112345678"
}
```

Comment: I edited your question to improve formatting and readability, which will be visible as soon as the edit is approved.

Answer (score 26):

You need to provide the same amount of `Default Values` as for JSON Path Expresions and Variable Names.

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Variable names: `VoidTransactionReferenceNumber;CILAmount`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.VoidTransactionReferenceNumber;$.CILAmount`
   - Default values: `NOT_FOUND; NOT_FOUND`

     [image: JMeter JSON Extractor]
3. As a result you will have the following JMeter Variables defined

   [image: JMeter JSON Extractor Variables]
4. You will be able to refer them as `${VoidTransactionReferenceNumber}` and `${CILAmount}` where required.

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)